# Where I can ask the question about applying for a short term license in Spain?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I'm not spanish, but I'd like to live in Spain as an expatriate, therefore I've asked the following question:

[How easy is to get a license to let a private home to tourists on a short term basis?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2869/)

but it was closed as off-topic.

Is there any other SE site where I can ask that question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because a question is off topic on this site, does not mean it is on topic somewhere else. I don't see how your question is related to living in Spain as an expat. I think that there is something I (and others) are missing from your question. Why do you need a short term rental license to live in a house you own?

Comment: In example, a lot of people buying 5-6 bedroom flats/houses in Spain and they're living in 1 room and renting the other rooms.

Comment: @kenorb ahh, if you add that in I think it would be reasonable to reopen.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've improved the question.